# AngularJS set html properties

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

we are pretty bloody beginners with JavaScript and AngularJS, but the scenarios is pretty simple. We want to set html properties received from a REST service.

This is our profileController.js:

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function($scope, $http) {

        // REST service works properly
    var resource = 'http://localhost:8080/user';

    $http.get(resource).then(function(result){

            // logs right json
            console.log(result);

            // no effect
            $scope.content = result.data.toString();

            // no effect
            if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });

} ]);
```

profile.html

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <br><br><br>
        <h2 class="sub-header">Profile</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Forename</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                    <th>E-Mail</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{profile.data}}</td>
                    <!-- Doesn't work as well
                    <td>{{profile.forename}}</td>
                    <td>{{profile.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{profile.role}}</td>
                    <td>{{profile.email}}</td>-->
                </tr>
                <div id="container" ng-controller="profileController">
                    <content-item forename="item"></content-item>
                </div>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The REST service works properly and sends the json back, the log outputs in the JavaScript console are right, just the setting in html doesn't work and we have absolutely no clue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the `.toString()` if you are receiving a list of users?

Comment: +1, the toString() should simply not be here, you are no longer manipulating a json object after this line.

Comment: It was just a demonstration that nothing works:
$scope.content = result.data;
$scope.forename = 'hallo';
this.lastname = 'lastname';

Comment: Those `td`s are not descendent elements of `div#container`, on which `ng-controller` is defined. So, "not work" is just the right behavior. Try move `ng-controller="profileController"` to the `table` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8ADRBsEbpkmaIHI9rrNR?p=preview).

```
app.controller("myController", [
      "$scope",
      function($scope){

        $scope.content = [
          {
            "firstname": "Natalie",
            "lastname": "Portman",
            "role": "Accountancy",
            "email": "n.p@email.com"
          },
          {
            "firstname": "Johnny",
            "lastname": "Depp",
            "role": "Sales Management",
            "email": "j.d@email.com"
          },
          {
            "firstname": "Kevin",
            "lastname": "Costner",
            "role": "Crisis control",
            "email": "k.c@email.com"
          },
        ];
      }]);
```

Where the above `$scope.content` is a hardcoded simulation of your `$scope.content = result.data;`.

And usage:

```
<tr ng-repeat="profile in content">
  <td>#</td>
  <td>{{profile.firstname}}</td>
  <td>{{profile.lastname}}</td>
  <td>{{profile.role}}</td>
  <td>{{profile.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

*Check the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8ADRBsEbpkmaIHI9rrNR?p=preview) for the complete code.*

PS: I changed the `{{profile.data}}` to `#` for the example, as I don't know what that's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
    Check your ng-controller and ng-app too, this [step](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) in [the angular tutoria](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)l should be fine for this.

Here, in your code, the ng-controller should be at least in the table tag i.e

```
<div>
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br>
    <h2 class="sub-header">Profile</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="profileController">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Forename</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>E-Mail</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{content}}</td>
                <!-- Doesn't work as well
                <td>{{content.forename}}</td>
                <td>{{content.lastname}}</td>
                <td>{{content.role}}</td>
                <td>{{content.email}}</td>-->
            </tr>
            <div id="container">
                <content-item forename="item"></content-item>
            </div>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert

```
$scope.content = result.data.toString();
```

to this:

```
$scope.content = result.data;
```

And if you want to print the data inside

```
<td>{{profile.data}}</td>
```

you have to change position of controller in html tag..